# Languages supersite on Codidact

Tags: discussion

There's a [proposal for a Languages site](https://meta.codidact.com/questions/276701) on [Codidact](https://codidact.org/), a Q&A site created by users who left StackExchange, that I've proposed taking the idea from Rebecca Stones's [Languages.SE proposal on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29986/163293). Like the Area 51 proposal, this Codidact site is aimed to include questions on any human language, natural or constructed.

I brought it up here because it seemed like something this community would be interested in. Codidact is ["currently only creating sites that have a community already interested"](https://meta.codidact.com/questions/276139#answer-276141), so if there is enough people here interested in such a proposal, it should have a good chance of launching.

Comment: The site has [launched](https://languages.codidact.com/) now.